# Page break in a table

Tags: tables, formatting

I've made a longtable in Latex but it is too long to be in one page, how can I insert a pagebreak to continue the table into the next page?

I have tried but its not working. Kindly help me

```
\begin{table*}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}
        \toprule
        Year      & Journal                                                     & Paper                                                 & Description                                                                                                 & Attack Type \\
        \midrule

        \ch{1995} & Journal of Moderen optics                                   & et al. Phoenix \cite{phoenix1995multi}                & \makecell {proposed technique to allow multi-user secure key distribution                                                 \\ on optical networks} & Eavesdropping \\

        \ch{1997} & IEEE network                                                & et al. Medard \cite{medard1997security}               & \makecell {Provide overview of physical layer security about tapping                                                      \\ and eavesdropping attacks in optical passive network} & Survey Paper \\

        \ch{1998} & \makecell {Multimedia Networks: Security,                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ Displays, Terminals, and Gateways} & et al. Marquis \cite{marquis1998physical} & \makecell {The paper explain different propectus \\ of physical layer security in all optical network} & Survey Paper \\

        \ch{1998} & \makecell {NDSS}                                            & et al. Bergman \cite{bergman1998distributed}          & \makecell {The paper proposed algorithm for attack localization in in                                                     \\ optical networks} & Attack Management  \\

        \ch{2002} & \makecell {IEEE Communications Magazine}                    & et al. Stok \cite{stok2002role}                       & \makecell {The paper investigated CDMA technique to secure data                                                           \\ in optical networks} & Eavesdropping \\

        \ch{2002} & \makecell {Optical Networking and                                                                                                                                                                                                               \\ Communications} & et al. Deng \cite{deng2002analysis} & \makecell {The paperStudied the effect of gain competition attack \\ in WDM link of optical network} & Gain Competition  \\

        \ch{2003} & \makecell {Proceedings of 2003 5th International Conference                                                                                                                                                                                     \\ on Transparent Optical Networks} & et al. Roh \cite{roh2003security} & \makecell {The article propose the security model and the authentication \\ protocol for eavesdropping and denial of service attacks} & \makecell { Eavesdropping \\ and Crosstalk} \\

        \ch{2003} & \makecell {IEEE Global Telecommunications                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ Conference} & et al. Wu\cite{wu2003necessary} & \makecell {This article focuses on crosstalk attacks, develops crosstalk \\ attack models, performs monitoring, and proposes effective monitor \\ placement strategies for such networks} & \makecell { Crosstalk} \\

        \ch{2003} & \makecell {Proceedings of 2003 5th International Conference                                                                                                                                                                                     \\ on Transparent Optical Networks} & et al. Machuca\cite{machuca2003failure} & \makecell {This article describes the fault location issues \\ involved in network fault management} & \makecell { Attack Managment} \\


        \ch{2004} & \makecell {IEEE Military Communications                                                                                                                                                                                                         \\ Conference} & et al. Shaneman \cite{shaneman2004optical} & \makecell {The article provide the comprehensive overview of different type of \\ attacks and the way to minimize it } & \makecell { Survey Paper} \\

        \ch{2005} & \makecell {IEEE/ACM Transactions on                                                                                                                                                                                                             \\ networking} & et al. Wu \cite{wu2005cross} & \makecell {This article focuses on crosstalk attacks, develops crosstalk \\ attack models, performs monitoring, and proposes effective monito} & \makecell { Crosstalk } \\

        \ch{2006} & \makecell {Cluster Computing}                               & et al. Wu \cite{wu2006attack}                         & \makecell {This article focuses on crosstalk attacks, develops crosstalk                                                  \\ attack models, performs monitoring, and proposes effective monito} & \makecell { Crosstalk } \\

        \ch{2006} & \makecell {Information Security Magazine}                   & et al. Miller \cite{miller2006fiber}                  & \makecell {The article identifies and explains the major threats and identifies                                           \\ potential attack methods that can take advantage of these threats.} & \makecell { Eavesdropping \\ and Crosstalk } \\


        \ch{2006} & \makecell {IEEE Communications Magazine}                    & et al. Rejeb \cite{rejeb2006fault}                    & \makecell {This article considers management issues, with particular emphasis on                                          \\ the complexity caused by the unique characteristics and \\ special behavior of transparent network components} & \makecell { Attack Management } \\


        \ch{2007} & \makecell {IEEE Journal on Selected                                                                                                                                                                                                             \\ Areas in Communications} & et al. Liu \cite{liu2007resilience} & \makecell {The author developed a cross-layer model to characterize the \\ attack propagation in the network, and studied the elasticity of the \\ AON architecture at the physical layer and the network layer} & \makecell { Crosstalk } \\

        \ch{2007} & \makecell {IEEE Photonics Technology Letters}               & et al. Nadarajah \cite{nadarajah2006implementation}   & \makecell {The article outlines the security of WDM optical networks,                                                     \\ discusses advanced encryption methods derived from quantum mechanics \\ (called quantum cryptography), and identifies specific vulnerabilities} & \makecell { Eavesdropping } \\

        \ch{2008} & \makecell {2008 2nd ICTON Mediterranean Winter}             & et al. Castanon \cite{castanon2008security}           & \makecell {This article believes that multipath routing is a promising direction to                                       \\ provide security protection for future optical network failures and attacks.} & \makecell { Eavesdropping and Crosstalk } \\

        \ch{2009} & \makecell {IEEE/ACM transactions                                                                                                                                                                                                                \\ on networking} & et al. Skorin-Kapov \cite{skorin2009new} & \makecell {By minimizing the maximum light path attack radius, the author \\ can limit the maximum interference caused by various physical layer attacks. Therefore, this article \\ can improve network security and robustness through careful network planning.} & \makecell {Crosstalk } \\

        \ch{2009} & \makecell {2009 Asia Communications and Photonics                                                                                                                                                                                               \\ conference and Exhibition} & et al. Prucnal \cite{prucnal2009physical} & \makecell {By Using optical processing technology, article has experimentally \\ enhanced the physical layer security of optical communication systems..} & \makecell {Eavesdropping } \\

        \ch{2009} & \makecell {IEEE International Conference on Communications} & et al. Kartalopoulos \cite{kartalopoulos2009security} & \makecell {This article studies the security of advanced optical                                                          \\ networks, optical fibers and free space optics, and describes quantum cryptography. It can also \\ identify vulnerabilities and discuss detection mechanisms and countermeasures against physical network attacks.} & \makecell {Eavesdropping } \\

        \ch{2009} & \makecell {Optics letters}                                  & et al. Fok \cite{fok2009all}                          & \makecell {The author uses the dual-pump four-wave mixing (FWM) in a 35 cm highly nonlinear bismuth                       \\ oxide fiber (Bi-NLF) to experimentally demonstrate optical encryption with interleaved band switching modulation.} & \makecell {Eavesdropping } \\

        \ch{2010} & \makecell {The 33rd International Convention MIPRO}         & et al. Furdek \cite{furdek2010gain}                   & \makecell {The article investigates the effects of gain competition with a case study                                     \\ in the laboratory and analyze its impact on network operation} & \makecell {Gain Competition  } \\

        \ch{2010} & \makecell {Journal of Networks}                             & et al. Rejeb \cite{rejeb2010control}                  & \makecell {This article briefly outlines the security and management issues that arise in all                             \\-optical networks, and then discusses the key management functions responsible for \\ ensuring network security and continuous operation.} & \makecell {Attack Management } \\

        \ch{2010} & \makecell {Journal of Optical Communications                                                                                                                                                                                                    \\ and Networking} & et al. Furdek \cite{furdek2010attack} & \makecell {The article proposes a novel preventive network planning method \\ to increase the network's resilience to in-band crosstalk attacks in a cost-effective manner without \\ using additional equipment or resources for post-attack recovery} & \makecell {Crosstalk} \\

        \ch{2011} & \makecell {JIEEE Transactions on Information                                                                                                                                                                                                    \\ Forensics and Security} & et al. Fok \cite{fok2011optical} & \makecell {This article discusses various types of security threats that may \\ appear in the optical layer of optical networks, including interference, physical infrastructure attacks, eavesdropping \\ and interception, and then focuses on improving the security of optical networks in the specific areas mentioned above.} & \makecell {Survey Paper} \\

        \ch{2011} & \makecell {2011 Proceedings of the 34th International                                                                                                                                                                                           \\ Convention MIPRO} & et al. Furdek \cite{furdek2011physical} & \makecell {The article focused on different type of attacks and the way \\ to enhance them} & \makecell {Survey Paper} \\

        \ch{2011} & \makecell {Optical Engineering}                             & et al. Peng \cite{peng2011propagation}                & \makecell {This paper improves the existing work to study the damage and propagation effects of                           \\ all-optical crosstalk attacks (including intra-channel and inter-channel crosstalk attacks)} & \makecell {Crosstalk} \\

        \ch{2011} & \makecell {European Conference and Exposition on                                                                                                                                                                                                \\ Optical Communications} & et al. Winzer \cite{winzer2011penalties} & \makecell {This paper uses simulation and 21.4-GBaud \\ QPSK, 16-QAM and 64-QAM experiments to quantify the crosstalk penalty that increases when the \\ constellation size is increased in a single-polarization QAM system.)} & \makecell {Crosstalk} \\

        \ch{2011} & \makecell {IET optoelectronics}                             & et al. Dahan \cite{dahan2011optical}                  & \makecell {Conducted a comprehensive analysis and investigation on Optical Performance Monitoring                         \\ (OPM) to achieve the deployment of translucent/transparent optical networks)} & \makecell {Attack Monitoring} \\

        \ch{2012} & \makecell {Optics express}                                  & et al. Guimor \cite{guiomar2012mitigation}            & \makecell {Based on the analytical closed form solution of the third-order Volterra kernel in the frequency               \\ domain, the Volterra series nonlinear equalizer is used to solve the problem of nonlinear \\ compensation in the channel)} & \makecell {Crosstalk} \\

        \ch{2012} & \makecell {Journal of Lightwave Technology}                 & et al. Habib \cite{habib2012design}                   & \makecell {This article proposes a disaster protection scheme using anycast, which provides                               \\ more protection, but uses less capacity than dedicated single-link failure protection)} & \makecell {Disaster } \\

        \ch{2012} & \makecell {Optical Communications Systems}                  & et al. Furdek \cite{furdek2012physical}               & \makecell {This chapter outlines the vulnerability of transparent optical networks (TON) to various                       \\ physical layer attacks. In addition, methods of attack detection and location and various countermeasures \\ against attacks are described.} & \makecell {Survey Paper } \\

        \ch{2012} & \makecell {1st International Conference on Recent                                                                                                                                                                                               \\ Advances in Information Technology} & et al. Sharma \cite{sharma2012effects} & \makecell {This article analyzes the impact of crosstalk on the transmission layer of AON, \\ and also shows that the input power needs to be optimized to resist crosstalk damage. In addition to this advanced \\ modulation format, it can also resist the effects of crosstalk in the case of fiber nonlinearity.} & \makecell {Crosstalk} \\

        \ch{2013} & \makecell {Computer Communications}                         & et al. Habib \cite{habib2013disaster}                 & \makecell {This article categorizes disasters according to their characteristics and discusses                            \\methods to deal with them. It also provides different protection schemes for different types of disasters, routing (single path and multipath\\), reconfiguration, excess capacity management, and different levels of protection according to network \\ load to minimize the possibility of mutual interference} & \makecell {Disaster} \\

        \ch{2013} & \makecell {17th International Conference on Optical                                                                                                                                                                                             \\ Networking Design and Modeling} & et al. Furdek \cite{furdek2013attack} & \makecell {The article proposes a novel concept that identifies the so-called \\ attack group (AG) of each optical path, and develops a dedicated path protection method that can ensure that the main \\ path and backup path of each connection are not protected from The impact of the attack group, the \\ purpose is to reduce the maximum potential damage caused by these attacks} & \makecell {Crosstalk} \\


        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Sample table}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please post full minimal examples not sniplets others cannot work with. (3) Standard tables cannot be broken across pages. You might want to have a look at the `longtable` package (note that `longtable` cannot be combined with `table*` as a float (`table*`) by its very definition cannot span more than one page.

Comment: Since your table cells contain quite a lot of text, you might want to take a look at the xltabular package which enables tables to automatically break across pages while it also offers the X colum type whose width adapts to the overall table width and therefore allows automatic line breaks inside of table cells.

Comment: How or where is `\ch` defined?

Comment: \begin{table*}[h]

  \centering

  \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}

    \toprule

    Year  & Journal    & Paper & Description& Attack Type \\
    \midrule
    
    \ch{1995} & Journal of Moderen optics & et al. Phoenix \cite{phoenix1995multi} & \makecell {proposed technique to allow multi-user secure key distribution \\ on optical networks} & Eavesdropping \\
    
 
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Sample table}
\end{table*}

Comment: Please make your example code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. From you use of `table*` I assume, you are using a two column document class. Is that correct? What is the `\ch` command supposed to do? Did you define it yourself or did you load a package that provides this command?

Comment: Probably you could use some kind of list-like presentation for this kind of contents in order to avoid the large white spaces that you will most likely get.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you employ a `longtable` environment, get rid of all `\makecell` wrappers, and use the `p` column type for the contents of columns 2 thru 5, to allow automatic line-wrapping.

The following screenshot shows just the first few rows of the `longtable`, which spans more than 7 pages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable,array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\providecommand\ch[1]{#1} % dummy definition

\begin{document}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{}lP{2.5cm}P{1.25cm}P{4.25cm}P{1.5cm}@{}}

%% Headers and footers:

        \caption{A very long table}\\
        \toprule
        Year & Journal & Paper & Description & Attack Type \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        
        \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, cont'd}\\
        \addlinespace
        \toprule
        Year & Journal & Paper & Description & Attack Type \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{\footnotesize\em Cont'd on following page}
        \endfoot
        
        \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot

%% Body of longtable
        \ch{1995} 
        & Journal of Moderen optics
        & et al. Phoenix \cite{phoenix1995multi}
        & proposed technique to allow multi-user secure key distribution on optical networks
        & Eavesdropping \\

        \ch{1997}
        & IEEE network
        & et al. Medard \cite{medard1997security}
        & Provide overview of physical layer security about tapping and eavesdropping attacks in optical passive network
        & Survey Paper \\

        \ch{1998}
        & Multimedia Networks: Security, Displays, Terminals, and Gateways
        & et al. Marquis \cite{marquis1998physical}
        & The paper explain different propectus of physical layer security in all optical network
        & Survey Paper \\

        \ch{1998}
        & NDSS
        & et al. Bergman \cite{bergman1998distributed}
        & The paper proposed algorithm for attack localization in optical networks
        & Attack Management  \\

        \ch{2002}
        & IEEE Communications Magazine
        & et al. Stok \cite{stok2002role}
        & The paper investigated CDMA technique to secure data in optical networks
        & Eavesdropping \\

        \ch{2002}
        & Optical Networking and Communications
        & et al. Deng \cite{deng2002analysis}
        & The paper studied the effect of gain competition attack in WDM link of optical network
        & Gain Competition  \\

        \ch{2003}
        & Proceedings of 2003 5th International Conference on Transparent Optical Networks
        & et al. Roh \cite{roh2003security}
        & The article propose the security model and the authentication protocol for eavesdropping and denial of service attacks
        & Eavesdropping and Crosstalk \\

        \ch{2003}
        & IEEE Global Telecommunications Conference
        & et al. Wu \cite{wu2003necessary}
        & This article focuses on crosstalk attacks, develops crosstalk attack models, performs monitoring, and proposes effective monitor placement strategies for such networks
        &  Crosstalk \\

        \ch{2003}
        & Proceedings of 2003 5th International Conference on Transparent Optical Networks
        & et al. Machuca \cite{machuca2003failure}
        & This article describes the fault location issues involved in network fault management
        & Attack Management \\

        \ch{2004}
        & IEEE Military Communications Conference
        & et al. Shaneman \cite{shaneman2004optical}
        & The article provide the comprehensive overview of different type of attacks and the way to minimize it
        & Survey Paper \\

        \ch{2005}
        & IEEE/ACM Transactions on networking
        & et al. Wu \cite{wu2005cross}
        & This article focuses on crosstalk attacks, develops crosstalk attack models, performs monitoring, and proposes effective monito
        &  Crosstalk  \\

        \ch{2006}
        & Cluster Computing
        & et al. Wu \cite{wu2006attack}
        & This article focuses on crosstalk attacks, develops crosstalk attack models, performs monitoring, and proposes effective monito
        &  Crosstalk \\

        \ch{2006}
        & Information Security Magazine
        & et al. Miller \cite{miller2006fiber}
        & The article identifies and explains the major threats and identifies potential attack methods that can take advantage of these threats. &
        Eavesdropping and Crosstalk \\

        \ch{2006}
        & IEEE Communications Magazine
        & et al. Rejeb \cite{rejeb2006fault}
        & This article considers management issues, with particular emphasis on the complexity caused by the unique characteristics and special behavior of transparent network components
        & Attack Management \\

        \ch{2007}
        & IEEE Journal on Selected Areas in Communications
        & et al. Liu \cite{liu2007resilience}
        & The author developed a cross-layer model to characterize the attack propagation in the network, and studied the elasticity of the AON architecture at the physical layer and the network layer
        & Crosstalk \\

        \ch{2007}
        & IEEE Photonics Technology Letters
        & et al. Nadarajah \cite{nadarajah2006implementation}
        & The article outlines the security of WDM optical networks, discusses advanced encryption methods derived from quantum mechanics (called quantum cryptography), and identifies specific vulnerabilities
        & Eavesdropping \\

        \ch{2008}
        & 2008 2nd ICTON Mediterranean Winter
        & et al. Castanon \cite{castanon2008security}
        & This article believes that multipath routing is a promising direction to provide security protection for future optical network failures and attacks.
        & Eavesdropping and Crosstalk  \\

        \ch{2009}
        & IEEE/ACM transactions on networking
        & et al. Skorin-Kapov \cite{skorin2009new}
        & By minimizing the maximum light path attack radius, the author can limit the maximum interference caused by various physical layer attacks. Therefore, this article can improve network security and robustness through careful network planning.
        & Crosstalk  \\

        \ch{2009} & 2009 Asia Communications and Photonics conference and Exhibition
        & et al. Prucnal \cite{prucnal2009physical}
        & By Using optical processing technology, article has experimentally enhanced the physical layer security of optical communication systems.
        & Eavesdropping \\

        \ch{2009}
        & IEEE International Conference on Communications
        & et al. Kartalopoulos \cite{kartalopoulos2009security}
        & This article studies the security of advanced optical networks, optical fibers and free space optics, and describes quantum cryptography. It can also identify vulnerabilities and discuss detection mechanisms and countermeasures against physical network attacks.
        & Eavesdropping \\

        \ch{2009} & Optics letters
        & et al. Fok \cite{fok2009all}
        & The author uses the dual-pump four-wave mixing (FWM) in a 35\,cm highly nonlinear bismuth oxide fiber (Bi-NLF) to experimentally demonstrate optical encryption with interleaved band switching modulation.
        & Eavesdropping  \\

        \ch{2010}
        & The 33rd International Convention MIPRO
        & et al. Furdek \cite{furdek2010gain}
        & The article investigates the effects of gain competition with a case study in the laboratory and analyze its impact on network operatio
        & Gain Competition \\

        \ch{2010}
        & Journal of Networks
        & et al. Rejeb \cite{rejeb2010control}
        & This article briefly outlines the security and management issues that arise in all optical networks, and then discusses the key management functions responsible for ensuring network security and continuous operation.
        & Attack Management  \\

        \ch{2010}
        & Journal of Optical Communications and Networking
        & et al. Furdek \cite{furdek2010attack}
        & The article proposes a novel preventive network planning method to increase the network's resilience to in-band crosstalk attacks in a cost-effective manner without using additional equipment or resources for post-attack recovery
        & Crosstalk \\

        \ch{2011}
        & JIEEE Transactions on Information Forensics and Security
        & et al. Fok \cite{fok2011optical}
        & This article discusses various types of security threats that may appear in the optical layer of optical networks, including interference, physical infrastructure attacks, eavesdropping and interception, and then focuses on improving the security of optical networks in the specific areas mentioned above.
        & Survey Paper \\

        \ch{2011}
        & 2011 Proceedings of the 34th International Convention MIPRO
        & et al. Furdek \cite{furdek2011physical}
        & The article focused on different type of attacks and the way to enhance them
        & Survey Paper \\

        \ch{2011}
        & Optical Engineering
        & et al. Peng \cite{peng2011propagation}
        & This paper improves the existing work to study the damage and propagation effects of all-optical crosstalk attacks (including intra-channel and inter-channel crosstalk attacks)
        & Crosstalk \\

        \ch{2011}
        & European Conference and Exposition on Optical Communications
        & et al. Winzer \cite{winzer2011penalties}
        & This paper uses simulation and 21.4-GBaud QPSK, 16-QAM and 64-QAM experiments to quantify the crosstalk penalty that increases when the constellation size is increased in a single-polarization QAM system.)
        & Crosstalk \\

        \ch{2011}
        & IET optoelectronics
        & et al. Dahan \cite{dahan2011optical}
        & Conducted a comprehensive analysis and investigation on Optical Performance Monitoring (OPM) to achieve the deployment of translucent/transparent optical networks)
        & Attack Monitoring \\

        \ch{2012}
        & Optics express
        & et al. Guimor \cite{guiomar2012mitigation}
        & Based on the analytical closed form solution of the third-order Volterra kernel in the frequency domain, the Volterra series nonlinear equalizer is used to solve the problem of nonlinear compensation in the channel)
        & Crosstalk \\

        \ch{2012} & Journal of Lightwave Technology
        & et al. Habib \cite{habib2012design}
        & This article proposes a disaster protection scheme using anycast, which provides more protection, but uses less capacity than dedicated single-link failure protection)
        & Disaster  \\

        \ch{2012}
        & Optical Communications Systems
        & et al. Furdek \cite{furdek2012physical}
        & This chapter outlines the vulnerability of transparent optical networks (TON) to various physical layer attacks. In addition, methods of attack detection and location and various countermeasures against attacks are described.
        & Survey Paper  \\

        \ch{2012} & 1st International Conference on Recent Advances in Information Technology
        & et al. Sharma \cite{sharma2012effects}
        & This article analyzes the impact of crosstalk on the transmission layer of AON, and also shows that the input power needs to be optimized to resist crosstalk damage. In addition to this advanced modulation format, it can also resist the effects of crosstalk in the case of fiber nonlinearity.
        & Crosstalk \\

        \ch{2013}
        & Computer Communications
        & et al. Habib \cite{habib2013disaster}
        & This article categorizes disasters according to their characteristics and discusses methods to deal with them. It also provides different protection schemes for different types of disasters, routing (single path and multipath), reconfiguration, excess capacity management, and different levels of protection according to network load to minimize the possibility of mutual interference
        & Disaster \\

        \ch{2013}
        & 17th International Conference on Optical Networking Design and Modeling
        & et al. Furdek \cite{furdek2013attack}
        & The article proposes a novel concept that identifies the so-called attack group (AG) of each optical path, and develops a dedicated path protection method that can ensure that the main path and backup path of each connection are not protected from The impact of the attack group, the purpose is to reduce the maximum potential damage caused by these attacks
        & Crosstalk \\

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Mico gave the correct answer. I just want to share a couple of subtleties that I use a lot: using landscape mode, avoiding hyphenation, and stretching rows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{makecell} %not used
\usepackage{array}  % stretch rows

\usepackage{pdflscape}  % landscape enviroment
\usepackage{caption} % caption the table

\newcommand{\ch}{}% nnuled

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{150pt}}   


\begin{document}        
        
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3} %array 

\clearpage% Flush earlier floats 
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen % avoid hyphens
\hyphenpenalty=10000 % avoid hyphens
\hbadness=10000 % avoid hyphens

\begin{landscape}% Landscape page
\footnotesize
\begin{center}      
        
\begin{longtable}{@{}cRlm{220pt}m{70pt}@{}} 

    \captionsetup{labelformat=empty,justification=centering}
    \caption{{\Large Table caption} }\\ 
    \toprule
    Year  &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Journal}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Paper}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Description}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Attack Type} \\
    \midrule
    
    \ch{1995} & Journal of Moderen optics  & et al. Phoenix \cite{phoenix1995multi} & {proposed technique to allow multi-user secure key    distribution on optical networks} & Eavesdropping  \\
    
    \ch{1997} & IEEE network & et al. Medard \cite{medard1997security} 
    &  {Provide overview of physical layer security about
    tapping  and eavesdropping attacks in optical passive
    network} & Survey Paper \\
    
    \ch{1998} &  {Multimedia Networks: Security,  Displays, Terminals, and Gateways} & et al. Marquis \cite{marquis1998physical} &  {The paper explain different propectus  of physical layer security in all optical network} & Survey Paper \\
    
    \ch{1998} &  {NDSS} & et al. Bergman \cite{bergman1998distributed} &  {The paper proposed algorithm for attack localization in in  optical networks} & Attack Management \\
    
    \ch{2002} &  {IEEE Communications Magazine} & et al. Stok \cite{stok2002role} 
    &  {The paper investigated CDMA technique to secure      data 
    in optical networks} & Eavesdropping \\
    
    
    \ch{2002} &  {Optical Networking and  Communications} & et al. Deng \cite{deng2002analysis} &  {The paperStudied the effect of gain competition attack  in WDM link of optical network} & Gain Competition \\
    
    \ch{2003} &  {Proceedings of 2003 5th International Conference  on Transparent Optical Networks} & et al. Roh \cite{roh2003security} &  {The article propose the security model and the authentication  protocol for eavesdropping and denial of service attacks} &  {Eavesdropping  and Crosstalk} \\
    
    \ch{2003} &  {IEEE Global Telecommunications  Conference} & et al. Wu\cite{wu2003necessary} &  {This article focuses on crosstalk attacks, develops crosstalk  attack models, performs monitoring, and proposes effective monitor  placement strategies for such networks} &  {Crosstalk} \\
    
    \ch{2003} &  {Proceedings of 2003 5th International Conference  on Transparent Optical Networks} & et al. Machuca\cite{machuca2003failure} &  {This article describes the fault location issues  involved in network fault management} &  {Attack Managment} \\
    
    
    \ch{2004} &  {IEEE Military Communications  Conference} & et al. Shaneman \cite{shaneman2004optical} &  {The article provide the comprehensive overview of different type of  attacks and the way to minimize it } &  {Survey Paper} \\
    
    \ch{2005} &  {IEEE/ACM Transactions on  networking} & et al. Wu \cite{wu2005cross} &  {This article focuses on crosstalk attacks, develops crosstalk  attack models, performs monitoring, and proposes effective monito} &  {Crosstalk } \\
    
    \ch{2006} &  {Cluster Computing} & et al. Wu \cite{wu2006attack} &  {This article focuses on crosstalk attacks, develops crosstalk  attack models, performs monitoring, and proposes effective monito} &  {Crosstalk } \\
    
    \ch{2006} &  {Information Security Magazine} & et al. Miller \cite{miller2006fiber} &  {The article identifies and explains the major threats and identifies  potential attack methods that can take advantage of these threats.} &  {Eavesdropping  and Crosstalk } \\
    
    
    \ch{2006} &  {IEEE Communications Magazine} & et al. Rejeb \cite{rejeb2006fault} &  {This article considers management issues, with particular emphasis on  the complexity caused by the unique characteristics and  special behavior of transparent network components} &  {Attack Management } \\
    
    
    \ch{2007} &  {IEEE Journal on Selected  Areas in Communications} & et al. Liu \cite{liu2007resilience} &  {The author developed a cross-layer model to characterize the  attack propagation in the network, and studied the elasticity of the  AON architecture at the physical layer and the network layer} &  {Crosstalk } \\
    
    \ch{2007} &  {IEEE Photonics Technology Letters} & et al. Nadarajah \cite{nadarajah2006implementation} &  {The article outlines the security of WDM optical networks,  discusses advanced encryption methods derived from quantum mechanics  (called quantum cryptography), and identifies specific vulnerabilities} &  {Eavesdropping } \\
    
    \ch{2008} &  {2008 2nd ICTON Mediterranean Winter} & et al. Castanon \cite{castanon2008security} &  {This article believes that multipath routing is a promising direction to  provide security protection for future optical network failures and attacks.} &  {Eavesdropping and Crosstalk } \\
    
    \ch{2009} &  {IEEE/ACM transactions on networking} & et al. Skorin-Kapov \cite{skorin2009new} &  {By minimizing the maximum light path attack radius, the author  can limit the maximum interference caused by various physical layer attacks. Therefore, this article  can improve network security and robustness through careful network planning.} &  {Crosstalk } \\
    
    \ch{2009} &  {2009 Asia Communications and       Photonics            conference and Exhibition} & et al. Prucnal \cite{prucnal2009physical} &  {By Using optical processing technology, article has experimentally  enhanced the physical layer security of optical communication systems..} &  {Eavesdropping } \\
    
    \ch{2009} &  {IEEE International Conference on Communications} & et al. Kartalopoulos \cite{kartalopoulos2009security} &  {This article studies the security of advanced optical networks, optical fibers and free space optics, and describes quantum cryptography. It can also  identify vulnerabilities and discuss detection mechanisms and countermeasures against physical network attacks.} &  {Eavesdropping } \\
    
    \ch{2009} &  {Optics letters}& et al. Fok \cite{fok2009all} &  {The author uses the dual-pump four-wave mixing (FWM) in a 35 cm highly nonlinear bismuth  oxide fiber (Bi-NLF) to experimentally demonstrate optical encryption with interleaved band switching modulation.} &  {Eavesdropping } \\
    
    \ch{2010} &  {The 33rd International Convention MIPRO} & et al. Furdek \cite{furdek2010gain} &  {The article investigates the effects of gain competition with a case study  in the laboratory and analyze its impact on network operation} &  {Gain Competition } \\
    
    \ch{2010} &  {Journal of Networks} & et al. Rejeb \cite{rejeb2010control}&  {This article briefly outlines the security and management issues that arise in all -optical networks, and then discusses the key management functions responsible for  ensuring network security and continuous operation.} &  {Attack Management } \\
    
    \ch{2010} &  {Journal of Optical Communications and Networking} & et al. Furdek \cite{furdek2010attack} &  {The article proposes a novel preventive network planning method  to increase the network's resilience to in-band crosstalk attacks in a cost-effective manner without  using additional equipment or resources for post-attack recovery} &  {Crosstalk} \\
    
    \ch{2011} &  {JIEEE Transactions on Information Forensics and Security} & et al. Fok \cite{fok2011optical} &  {This article discusses various types of security threats that may  appear in the optical layer of optical networks, including interference, physical infrastructure attacks, eavesdropping  and interception, and then focuses on improving the security of optical networks in the specific areas mentioned above.} &  {Survey Paper} \\
    
    \ch{2011} &  {2011 Proceedings of the 34th International  Convention MIPRO} & et al. Furdek \cite{furdek2011physical} &  {The article focused on different type of attacks and the way  to enhance them} &  {Survey Paper} \\
    
    \ch{2011} &  {Optical Engineering} & et al. Peng \cite{peng2011propagation}&  {This paper improves the existing work to study the damage and propagation effects of  all-optical crosstalk attacks (including intra-channel and inter-channel crosstalk attacks)} &  {Crosstalk} \\
    
    \ch{2011} &  {European Conference and Exposition on Optical Communications} & et al. Winzer \cite{winzer2011penalties} &  {This paper uses simulation and 21.4-GBaud  QPSK, 16-QAM and 64-QAM experiments to quantify the crosstalk penalty that increases when the  constellation size is increased in a single-polarization QAM system.)} &  {Crosstalk} \\
    
    \ch{2011} &  {IET optoelectronics} & et al. Dahan \cite{dahan2011optical}&  {Conducted a comprehensive analysis and investigation on Optical Performance Monitoring  (OPM) to achieve the deployment of translucent/transparent optical networks)} &  {Attack Monitoring} \\
    
    \ch{2012} &  {Optics express}& et al. Guimor \cite{guiomar2012mitigation}&  {Based on the analytical closed form solution of the third-order Volterra kernel in the frequency  domain, the Volterra series nonlinear equalizer is used to solve the problem of nonlinear  compensation in the channel)} &  {Crosstalk} \\
    
    \ch{2012} &  {Journal of Lightwave Technology} & et al. Habib \cite{habib2012design} &  {This article proposes a disaster protection scheme using anycast, which provides  more protection, but uses less capacity than dedicated single-link failure protection)} &  {Disaster } \\
    
    \ch{2012} &  {Optical Communications Systems}& et al. Furdek \cite{furdek2012physical} &  {This chapter outlines the vulnerability of transparent optical networks (TON) to various  physical layer attacks. In addition, methods of attack detection and location and various countermeasures  against attacks are described.} &  {Survey Paper } \\
    
    \ch{2012} &  {1st International Conference on Recent  Advances in Information Technology} & et al. Sharma \cite{sharma2012effects} &  {This article analyzes the impact of crosstalk on the transmission layer of AON,  and also shows that the input power needs to be optimized to resist crosstalk damage. In addition to this advanced  modulation format, it can also resist the effects of crosstalk in the case of fiber nonlinearity.} &  {Crosstalk} \\
    
    \ch{2013} &  {Computer Communications} & et al. Habib \cite{habib2013disaster} &  {This article categorizes disasters according to their characteristics and discussesmethods to deal with them. It also provides different protection schemes for different types of disasters, routing (single path and multipath), reconfiguration, excess capacity management, and different levels of protection according to network  load to minimize the possibility of mutual interference} &  {Disaster} \\
    
    \ch{2013} &  {17th International Conference on Optical  Networking Design and Modeling} & et al. Furdek \cite{furdek2013attack} &  {The article proposes a novel concept that identifies the so-called  attack group (AG) of each optical path, and develops a dedicated path protection method that can ensure that the main  path and backup path of each connection are not protected from The impact of the attack group, the  purpose is to reduce the maximum potential damage caused by these attacks} &  {Crosstalk} \\
    
    
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}%
\end{center}
\end{landscape}%


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. My apologies for this rather belated comment, but I noticed your answer only just now. My only comment is: Don't encase a `longtable` environment inside a `center` environment. `longtable` environments are automatically centered horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by splitting the table into two tables. It's a bit tedious since you have to adjust the size manually.

```
\begin{table*}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}
        \toprule
        Year      & Journal                                                     & Paper                                                 & Description                                                                                                 & Attack Type \\
        \midrule

        \ch{1995} & Journal of Moderen optics                                   & et al. Phoenix \cite{phoenix1995multi}                & \makecell {proposed technique to allow multi-user secure key distribution                                                 \\ on optical networks} & Eavesdropping \\

        \ch{1997} & IEEE network                                                & et al. Medard \cite{medard1997security}               & \makecell {Provide overview of physical layer security about tapping                                                      \\ and eavesdropping attacks in optical passive network} & Survey Paper \\

        \ch{1998} & \makecell {Multimedia Networks: Security,                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ Displays, Terminals, and Gateways} & et al. Marquis \cite{marquis1998physical} & \makecell {The paper explain different propectus \\ of physical layer security in all optical network} & Survey Paper \\

        \ch{1998} & \makecell {NDSS}                                            & et al. Bergman \cite{bergman1998distributed}          & \makecell {The paper proposed algorithm for attack localization in in                                                     \\ optical networks} & Attack Management  \\

        \ch{2002} & \makecell {IEEE Communications Magazine}                    & et al. Stok \cite{stok2002role}                       & \makecell {The paper investigated CDMA technique to secure data                                                           \\ in optical networks} & Eavesdropping \\

        \ch{2002} & \makecell {Optical Networking and                                                                                                                                                                                                               \\ Communications} & et al. Deng \cite{deng2002analysis} & \makecell {The paperStudied the effect of gain competition attack \\ in WDM link of optical network} & Gain Competition  \\

        \ch{2003} & \makecell {Proceedings of 2003 5th International Conference                                                                                                                                                                                     \\ on Transparent Optical Networks} & et al. Roh \cite{roh2003security} & \makecell {The article propose the security model and the authentication \\ protocol for eavesdropping and denial of service attacks} & \makecell { Eavesdropping \\ and Crosstalk} \\

        \ch{2003} & \makecell {IEEE Global Telecommunications                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ Conference} & et al. Wu\cite{wu2003necessary} & \makecell {This article focuses on crosstalk attacks, develops crosstalk \\ attack models, performs monitoring, and proposes effective monitor \\ placement strategies for such networks} & \makecell { Crosstalk} \\

        \ch{2003} & \makecell {Proceedings of 2003 5th International Conference                                                                                                                                                                                     \\ on Transparent Optical Networks} & et al. Machuca\cite{machuca2003failure} & \makecell {This article describes the fault location issues \\ involved in network fault management} & \makecell { Attack Managment} \\


        \ch{2004} & \makecell {IEEE Military Communications                                                                                                                                                                                                         \\ Conference} & et al. Shaneman \cite{shaneman2004optical} & \makecell {The article provide the comprehensive overview of different type of \\ attacks and the way to minimize it } & \makecell { Survey Paper} \\

        \ch{2005} & \makecell {IEEE/ACM Transactions on                                                                                                                                                                                                             \\ networking} & et al. Wu \cite{wu2005cross} & \makecell {This article focuses on crosstalk attacks, develops crosstalk \\ attack models, performs monitoring, and proposes effective monito} & \makecell { Crosstalk } \\

        \ch{2006} & \makecell {Cluster Computing}                               & et al. Wu \cite{wu2006attack}                         & \makecell {This article focuses on crosstalk attacks, develops crosstalk                                                  \\ attack models, performs monitoring, and proposes effective monito} & \makecell { Crosstalk } \\

        \ch{2006} & \makecell {Information Security Magazine}                   & et al. Miller \cite{miller2006fiber}                  & \makecell {The article identifies and explains the major threats and identifies                                           \\ potential attack methods that can take advantage of these threats.} & \makecell { Eavesdropping \\ and Crosstalk } \\


        \ch{2006} & \makecell {IEEE Communications Magazine}                    & et al. Rejeb \cite{rejeb2006fault}                    & \makecell {This article considers management issues, with particular emphasis on                                          \\ the complexity caused by the unique characteristics and \\ special behavior of transparent network components} & \makecell { Attack Management } \\


        \ch{2007} & \makecell {IEEE Journal on Selected                                                                                                                                                                                                             \\ Areas in Communications} & et al. Liu \cite{liu2007resilience} & \makecell {The author developed a cross-layer model to characterize the \\ attack propagation in the network, and studied the elasticity of the \\ AON architecture at the physical layer and the network layer} & \makecell { Crosstalk } \\

        \ch{2007} & \makecell {IEEE Photonics Technology Letters}               & et al. Nadarajah \cite{nadarajah2006implementation}   & \makecell {The article outlines the security of WDM optical networks,                                                     \\ discusses advanced encryption methods derived from quantum mechanics \\ (called quantum cryptography), and identifies specific vulnerabilities} & \makecell { Eavesdropping } \\

        \ch{2008} & \makecell {2008 2nd ICTON Mediterranean Winter}             & et al. Castanon \cite{castanon2008security}           & \makecell {This article believes that multipath routing is a promising direction to                                       \\ provide security protection for future optical network failures and attacks.} & \makecell { Eavesdropping and Crosstalk } \\

        \ch{2009} & \makecell {IEEE/ACM transactions                                                                                                                                                                                                                \\ on networking} & et al. Skorin-Kapov \cite{skorin2009new} & \makecell {By minimizing the maximum light path attack radius, the author \\ can limit the maximum interference caused by various physical layer attacks. Therefore, this article \\ can improve network security and robustness through careful network planning.} & \makecell {Crosstalk } \\

        \ch{2009} & \makecell {2009 Asia Communications and Photonics                                                                                                                                                                                               \\ conference and Exhibition} & et al. Prucnal \cite{prucnal2009physical} & \makecell {By Using optical processing technology, article has experimentally \\ enhanced the physical layer security of optical communication systems..} & \makecell {Eavesdropping } \\

        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Sample table}
\end{table*}

\begin{table*}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}

        \ch{2009} & \makecell {IEEE International Conference on Communications} & et al. Kartalopoulos \cite{kartalopoulos2009security} & \makecell {This article studies the security of advanced optical                                                          \\ networks, optical fibers and free space optics, and describes quantum cryptography. It can also \\ identify vulnerabilities and discuss detection mechanisms and countermeasures against physical network attacks.} & \makecell {Eavesdropping } \\

        \ch{2009} & \makecell {Optics letters}                                  & et al. Fok \cite{fok2009all}                          & \makecell {The author uses the dual-pump four-wave mixing (FWM) in a 35 cm highly nonlinear bismuth                       \\ oxide fiber (Bi-NLF) to experimentally demonstrate optical encryption with interleaved band switching modulation.} & \makecell {Eavesdropping } \\

        \ch{2010} & \makecell {The 33rd International Convention MIPRO}         & et al. Furdek \cite{furdek2010gain}                   & \makecell {The article investigates the effects of gain competition with a case study                                     \\ in the laboratory and analyze its impact on network operation} & \makecell {Gain Competition  } \\

        \ch{2010} & \makecell {Journal of Networks}                             & et al. Rejeb \cite{rejeb2010control}                  & \makecell {This article briefly outlines the security and management issues that arise in all                             \\-optical networks, and then discusses the key management functions responsible for \\ ensuring network security and continuous operation.} & \makecell {Attack Management } \\

        \ch{2010} & \makecell {Journal of Optical Communications                                                                                                                                                                                                    \\ and Networking} & et al. Furdek \cite{furdek2010attack} & \makecell {The article proposes a novel preventive network planning method \\ to increase the network's resilience to in-band crosstalk attacks in a cost-effective manner without \\ using additional equipment or resources for post-attack recovery} & \makecell {Crosstalk} \\

        \ch{2011} & \makecell {JIEEE Transactions on Information                                                                                                                                                                                                    \\ Forensics and Security} & et al. Fok \cite{fok2011optical} & \makecell {This article discusses various types of security threats that may \\ appear in the optical layer of optical networks, including interference, physical infrastructure attacks, eavesdropping \\ and interception, and then focuses on improving the security of optical networks in the specific areas mentioned above.} & \makecell {Survey Paper} \\

        \ch{2011} & \makecell {2011 Proceedings of the 34th International                                                                                                                                                                                           \\ Convention MIPRO} & et al. Furdek \cite{furdek2011physical} & \makecell {The article focused on different type of attacks and the way \\ to enhance them} & \makecell {Survey Paper} \\

        \ch{2011} & \makecell {Optical Engineering}                             & et al. Peng \cite{peng2011propagation}                & \makecell {This paper improves the existing work to study the damage and propagation effects of                           \\ all-optical crosstalk attacks (including intra-channel and inter-channel crosstalk attacks)} & \makecell {Crosstalk} \\

        \ch{2011} & \makecell {European Conference and Exposition on                                                                                                                                                                                                \\ Optical Communications} & et al. Winzer \cite{winzer2011penalties} & \makecell {This paper uses simulation and 21.4-GBaud \\ QPSK, 16-QAM and 64-QAM experiments to quantify the crosstalk penalty that increases when the \\ constellation size is increased in a single-polarization QAM system.)} & \makecell {Crosstalk} \\

        \ch{2011} & \makecell {IET optoelectronics}                             & et al. Dahan \cite{dahan2011optical}                  & \makecell {Conducted a comprehensive analysis and investigation on Optical Performance Monitoring                         \\ (OPM) to achieve the deployment of translucent/transparent optical networks)} & \makecell {Attack Monitoring} \\

        \ch{2012} & \makecell {Optics express}                                  & et al. Guimor \cite{guiomar2012mitigation}            & \makecell {Based on the analytical closed form solution of the third-order Volterra kernel in the frequency               \\ domain, the Volterra series nonlinear equalizer is used to solve the problem of nonlinear \\ compensation in the channel)} & \makecell {Crosstalk} \\

        \ch{2012} & \makecell {Journal of Lightwave Technology}                 & et al. Habib \cite{habib2012design}                   & \makecell {This article proposes a disaster protection scheme using anycast, which provides                               \\ more protection, but uses less capacity than dedicated single-link failure protection)} & \makecell {Disaster } \\

        \ch{2012} & \makecell {Optical Communications Systems}                  & et al. Furdek \cite{furdek2012physical}               & \makecell {This chapter outlines the vulnerability of transparent optical networks (TON) to various                       \\ physical layer attacks. In addition, methods of attack detection and location and various countermeasures \\ against attacks are described.} & \makecell {Survey Paper } \\

        \ch{2012} & \makecell {1st International Conference on Recent                                                                                                                                                                                               \\ Advances in Information Technology} & et al. Sharma \cite{sharma2012effects} & \makecell {This article analyzes the impact of crosstalk on the transmission layer of AON, \\ and also shows that the input power needs to be optimized to resist crosstalk damage. In addition to this advanced \\ modulation format, it can also resist the effects of crosstalk in the case of fiber nonlinearity.} & \makecell {Crosstalk} \\

        \ch{2013} & \makecell {Computer Communications}                         & et al. Habib \cite{habib2013disaster}                 & \makecell {This article categorizes disasters according to their characteristics and discusses                            \\methods to deal with them. It also provides different protection schemes for different types of disasters, routing (single path and multipath\\), reconfiguration, excess capacity management, and different levels of protection according to network \\ load to minimize the possibility of mutual interference} & \makecell {Disaster} \\

        \ch{2013} & \makecell {17th International Conference on Optical                                                                                                                                                                                             \\ Networking Design and Modeling} & et al. Furdek \cite{furdek2013attack} & \makecell {The article proposes a novel concept that identifies the so-called \\ attack group (AG) of each optical path, and develops a dedicated path protection method that can ensure that the main \\ path and backup path of each connection are not protected from The impact of the attack group, the \\ purpose is to reduce the maximum potential damage caused by these attacks} & \makecell {Crosstalk} \\


        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Sample table}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: in two column mode (which is the only time `table*` is not the same as `table`)  you can not use `[h]`. In one column mode it is unlikely that both tables can be `[h]` so this is likely to force the two halves of the table to drift apart and not be on consecutive pages. You are also numbering the two halves separately.